# WSO2 EI, How to restrict http access access to proxy services(soap, rest)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have developed numerous SOAP services using WSO2 EI 6.5.0.

And there is need to put restrict(access control) on some users(who call these services) to connect these services.

Q : Does WSO2 EI have this kind of features?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a security policy to define the required security configurations. Please check below [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service) on how to apply security to a proxy service.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the suitable security implementation from [Security Implementation documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Security+Implementation).

- Access control for SOAP services:
  https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+a+Proxy+Service
- Access control for REST APIs:
  https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Applying+Security+to+an+API

Thanks.